# SVG sprite with <object>

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design, vector-graphics

So I have a sprite SVG with lots of icons laid out in a grid like pattern (each has it's own 30 x 30 block) and until now I have been using this as a background image which has been working fine.

I have recently discovered that you can use CSS classes to change the fill colours of individual paths contained within the SVG. This would be great because I have a few chevron icons in my sprite and I've had to copy & paste them a bunch of times to get different coloured chevrons. It would be great if I could just have one chevron and change the colour dynamically.

I am aware that this cannot be done with the background-image method and the SVG has to actually be embedded on the page.

I'm curious as to what the best method for this is because I have quite a few icons in my sprite svg and rendering this all on the page just feels a bit painful.

Regardless, I had a go.

For this example, my sprite is 60 x 30, so there are two icons on it, I want the second one so my origin is -30, 0.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite-icon-test.svg#House1" width="30" height="30">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

I can't see the second icon because I can't specify an offset.

I was following the technique shown on this page http://www.sitepoint.com/use-svg-image-sprites/ but they place all their sprites on top of each other which would work fine but I don't want to put them all on top of each other because I have a lot of icons and it'll just be a nightmare.

Can anyone provide an alternative/way around this so that I can still apply styles to paths with CSS but retain my grid format. Also, embedding the whole SVG object in the page every time I want to use an icons seems a bit crazy when I have a large sprite with lots of icons on it and I imagine this would be terrible for performance so can anyone provide any information on whether this is avoidable or not?

**Update:**

This is where I've got to so far.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG Test</title>

    <style>
        .red {fill:#ec1937;}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <svg id="sprite" width="0" height="0">

        <g id="chevron">
            <path fill="#E8213B" d="M9.683,14.274c-0.378,0.399-0.378,1.053,0,1.452l5.932,6.264c0.378,0.399,1.006,0.408,1.395,0.019
                l1.286-1.286c0.389-0.389,0.389-1.026,0-1.415L14.7,15.707c-0.389-0.389-0.388-1.026,0-1.415l3.598-3.598
                c0.389-0.389,0.389-1.025,0-1.414L17.01,7.991c-0.389-0.389-1.016-0.38-1.395,0.019L9.683,14.274z"/>
        </g>

        <g id="house">
            <polygon fill="#3E123E" points="44.753,10.503 37.378,17.878 37.378,25.253 52.128,25.253 52.128,17.878   "/>
            <polygon fill="#3E123E" points="44.837,8.747 53.128,17.01 55.128,15.01 44.837,4.747 34.462,15.01 36.462,17.01   "/>
            <polygon fill="#3E123E" points="52.128,10.018 52.128,5.33 48.878,5.33 48.878,6.777  "/>
        </g>
    </svg>

    <svg width="30" height="30">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#house" class="red" x="-30" y="0"></use>
    </svg>

</body>
```

Sadly, the red styling does not apply when you use a  tag.

I also tried what was suggested by Erik but the SVG code is nowhere on the page so the CSS selector has nothing to target as the  tag is only referencing a  in the external SVG file.

Comment: You can probably use an SVG Fragment identifier with a translate transform for this. See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers

Comment: You're really asking two questions here. The more you change it to emphasise the second issue the less Eric's answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use <view> elements.

In your svg you define views as some particular area in your (larger) viewBox that shows just one of the resources inside:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <view id="star" viewBox="40 80 32 32" />
  ...
</svg>
```

Then you can reference that view from outside like this:

```
<img src="sprites.svg#star">
```

Here's a [full example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/linking/link-to-id.html) showing this.

Comment: Thanks Erik! I thought this was the whole answer until I tried adding a class to a polygon and realising it didn't change colour when I applied a fill in my css! :(. This kind of makes sense though as the svg elements aren't actually on the page so the css doesn't pick up the class.

Comment: Assuming you use <iframe>, <object> or <embed> for referencing (since that allows scripting inside the svg) you can pass in whatever data you want e.g in the url itself or via `window.postMessage`, then let a script inside the svg parse that into whatever you need, such as style. You will get two separate documents if you reference an external svg, your html and your svg, and stylerules only work/apply in the document they're included/referenced in, so you'll need to transfer them to where you need them when using two documents.